# How to use switch case in for loop?

Tags: c#, wpf, switch-statement

I've a menu which consists of items as below:

```
Orange
Apple
Lemon
Banana
```

Each item has their own Uid, e.g. 1 is Orange, 2 is Apple etc. When "Apple" is clicked from the menu, a message box will popup and display "Apple is chosen". I know that this can be done by using switch case, but instead of making it case by case, I want to make it more flexible. For example:

```
MenuItem menuItem=(MenuItem)e.OriginalSource;
int itemUid=Int32.Parse(menuItem.Uid);

for (itemUid = 1; itemUid <= menuItem.Items.Count; itemUid++)
{
  switch (itemUid)
  {
    case itemUid: Console.WriteLine("{0} is chosen", menuItem.Header); break;
  }
}
```

The problem is in case statement, it can only accept constant.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

Comment: an `if` statement would be better suited, since you only have one comparison anyways

Comment: Is this pseudo code? `case 1:` would work

Comment: you assign the parsed value to itemUid and discard it by assigning to it again just after in the for loop head. moreover, I'm not really sure what you're trying to do, could you try to explain more what you mean by "more flexible"?

Comment: `switch (itemUid)` and `case itemUid` don't seem to be logical...

Comment: how about a foreach?

Comment: Hi @Raptor, I know, but i just want to make it more flex

Comment: And why are you setting `itemUid` a value (in `int itemUid = Int32.Parse(menuItem.Uid)`) and then overwriting it with `itemUid = 1` inside your `for` statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exaclty what you're asking, but after some thinking I believe you want the same functionality that a switch-case would bring, only with less code duplication.

In that case I think something like this will do the trick:

```
var message = string.Format("{0} is selected.", ((MenuItem) e.Source).Header);
// Do something with message
```

Answer (score 2):

Suppose your menu

```
<Menu MenuItem.Click="CommonHandler">

  <MenuItem Header="Orange" Name="Orange"/>

  <MenuItem Header="Apple" Name="Apple"/>

  <MenuItem Header="Lemon" Name="Lemon"/>

  <MenuItem Header="Banana" Name="Banana"/>

</Menu>
```

In your click handler

try like this

```
void CommonHandler(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
MenuItem mi = e.Source as MenuItem;

  switch (mi.Name) {

    case "Orange":  //do something;

      break; 

    case "Apple":  //do something else

      break; 

    case "Lemon":  //something else again

      break; 
    case "Banana":  //something else again

      break; 

  }
}
```

Comment: Might wanna add a null check to mi after the conversion, although I guess it could be argued that if someone hooks this method up to the wrong event you WANT things to crash and burn.

Seems like the right solution though, if I understand OP correctly (which I most certainly might not), even though I really don't like those braces in the cases!

Comment: Hi @AnikIslamAbhi, I know it can be done that way, but I want it more flexible, since I retrieved those items from a xml, in case there is item update in xml, at least no need to do anything in the coding.

Comment: @YWah Then you can just print `mi.Name` instead of checking from my answer

Answer (score 1):

`switch` only supports constants as value in the `case`. From the [specs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664749(v=vs.71).aspx):

```
switch-label:
case   constant-expression   :
```

Use an `if`-statement instead.

Comment: Else you would have multiple `case`s. It's your only option.

Answer (score 0):

Switch statements are evaluated at compiling time. You can't use a switch in your case. You'll probably want to do an `if` `else` , or using your enums directly